# Applying a recursive function to a list to get another list

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

Here is a list:

```
x2={1539.91, 5.05, -2.82, 0, 19, 135.93, 117.78, 11.61, 8.17, 13.76, 
1.5, 36.75, 137.77, -16.18, 4.18, -2.82, 0, 18.42, 53.19, 5.91, 
-16.18, 3.24, -2.82, 0, 53.19, 518.6, -16.18, 1.61, -2.82, 23, 0, 
70.92, 58.89, 13.08, 42.32, 57.67, -15.32, 1.76, -2.68, 18.42, 0, 
53.19, 6.33, -15.32, 2.01, -2.68, 0, 53.19, -15.32, 2.17, -2.68, 0,
-1000, 76.83, 27.18, 0.02, 8.88, 13.08, 30, 48.72, 16.02, -15.32, 
1.69, -2.68, 0, 0.7, 53.19, 1128.85, 11.49, 53.19, 16.61, 209.84,
1243.2, 23, 1.08}
```

I want to create a new list called `balancelist` using a recursive function (or any other way so I learn) such that I end up with a list with something like this:

```
{1539.91,1539.91-5.05,1539.91-5.05-(-2.82),......}
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
balancefinal = {} 
For[i = 1, i <= Length[x2], i++, x2[[i]] - x2[[i + 1]]; 
Append[balancefinal]]
```

Answer (score 11):

If you consider [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate) a recursive function, then you could do:

```
2 x2[[1]] - Accumulate[x2]
```

This is much faster than using something like [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList). For example:

```
x2 = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10^6];

r1 = 2 x2[[1]] - Accumulate[x2]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = FoldList[Subtract, x2]; //AbsoluteTiming

MinMax[r1 - r2]
```

> {0.005461, Null}
>
> {0.161103, Null}
>
> {-3.86535*10^-12, 1.65983*10^-11}

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using? On my machine I have `r2` more efficient.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ r1 is much faster than r2 on all of my versions, from M9 to M11 on MacOS.

Comment: So it is very strange then. `In[35]:= RepeatedTiming[FoldList[Subtract, x2];]
RepeatedTiming[2 First[x2] - Accumulate[x2];]

Out[35]= {0.000015, Null}

Out[36]= {0.000037, Null}`

Comment: BTW, v11.3 on Win10

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I think you're using the OP x2, and not the x2 in my answer.

Comment: OK, you are right.

Comment: What is "OP" short for?

Comment: OP is either original post, or original poster.

Answer (score 8):

You can `Fold` `Subtract` on `x2`:

```
FoldList[Subtract] @ x2
```

> {1539.91,1534.86,1537.68,1537.68,1518.68,1382.75,1264.97,1253.36,1245.19,1231.43,1229.93,1193.18,1055.41,1071.59,1067.41,1070.23,1070.23,1051.81,998.62,992.71,1008.89,1005.65,1008.47,1008.47,955.28,436.68,452.86,451.25,454.07,431.07,431.07,360.15,301.26,288.18,245.86,188.19,203.51,201.75,204.43,186.01,186.01,132.82,126.49,141.81,139.8,142.48,142.48,89.29,104.61,102.44,105.12,105.12,1105.12,1028.29,1001.11,1001.09,992.21,979.13,949.13,900.41,884.39,899.71,898.02,900.7,900.7,900.,846.81,-282.04,-293.53,-346.72,-363.33,-573.17,-1816.37,-1839.37,-1840.45}

If you have to use `For` here is a modification of your code that gives the correct result:

```
balancefinal = {x2[[1]]};
For[i = 1, i < Length[x2], i++, AppendTo[balancefinal, balancefinal[[-1]] - x2[[i + 1]]]]

balancefinal == FoldList[Subtract, x2]
```

> True